# Couchbase/N1QL - Get all tie-in records that don't exist (opposite/inverse of inner join)

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Query to get tie-in records that DO exist (essentially, all manufacturer defects that exist):

```
select
      md.f_manufacturerId, md.f_defectId
  from productionlines as md
  inner join productionlines as m on m.type="manufacturer" and m.manufacturerId=md.f_manufacturerId
  inner join productionlines as d on d.type="defect" and d.defectId=md.f_defectId
  where md.type="manufacturerdefect"
  order by md.f_manufacturerId
```

I want the OPPOSITE/INVERSE of this...
I want to know the list of DEFECT TO MANUFACTURER tie-ins we DO NOT HAVE.

Structure of the Data...

MANUFACTURER:

```
{
  "name": "Ball Bearings"
  "id": "00a4260956d54e46932001d853df843c",
  "manufacturerId": 28,
  "type": "manufacturer"
}


{
  "name": "Wheel Rims"
  "id": "3ad4b5c6433d6e8b9c230fdd5dda8b33",
  "manufacturerId": 2,
  "type": "manufacturer"
}
```

DEFECT:

```
{
  "name": "Bad Drill Bit"
  "id": "c348fd358d10023964e45d6590624a00",
  "defectId": 7,
  "type": "defect"
}


{
  "name": "Bad Shipping"
  "id": "33b8add5ddf032c9b8e6d3346c5b4da3",
  "defectId": 9,
  "type": "defect"
}
```

MANUFACTURER DEFECTS:

```
{
  "id": "de426435bd10023964e45d6590624a00",
  "f_defectId": 7,
  "f_manufacturerId": 2,
  "type": "manufacturerdefect"
}

{
  "id": "de426435bd10023964e45d6590624a01",
  "f_defectId": 9,
  "f_manufacturerId": 2,
  "type": "manufacturerdefect"
}

{
  "id": "de426435bd10023964e45d6590624a02",
  "f_defectId": 7,
  "f_manufacturerId": 28,
  "type": "manufacturerdefect"
}

{
  "id": "de426435bd10023964e45d6590624a03",
  "f_defectId": 9,
  "f_manufacturerId": 28,
  "type": "manufacturerdefect"
}
```

So to be clear, if any of the manufacturer defects above DID NOT EXIST, I want to know all manufacturer and defect id combinations that are missing.

Comment: Okay, so to get all combinations (currently have many of these), I can run this query:

select
    m.manufacturerId as manufacturerId, d.defectId as defectId
from productionlines as d
inner join productionlines as m on m.type="manufacturer"
where d.type="defect"
order by m.manufacturerId

Now, if I could filter out of this list existing manufacturer defects... then return what remains...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STEP 1: Find all combinations.

STEP 2: Exclude all existing manufacturing defects.

```
(select
    m.manufacturerId as manufacturerId, d.defectId as defectId
from productionlines as d
inner join productionlines as m on m.type="manufacturer"
where d.type="defect"
order by m.manufacturerId)
EXCEPT
(select
    md.f_manufacturerId as manufacturerId, md.f_defectId as defectId
from productionlines as md
where md.type="manufacturerdefect")
order by manufacturerId
```